# How do you select a lower level item as the displaymember for a ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a List of FLECk.IWebSocketConnection

I am trying to display this list in a listbox using the IWebSocketConnection.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress property, but I must be doing something wrong

```
Sockets= new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
ListBox1.DataSource=Sockets;
ListBox1.DisplayMember="ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress";
```

When I add to Sockets using

```
Sockets.Add(socket);
```

I have to rebind the datasource

```
ListBox1.DataSource=Sockets;
ListBox1.DisplayMember="ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress";
```

But the display in the lisbox is "Fleck.WebSocketConnection" as opposed to the expected Ip number.

Just to clarify, The write number of connections are listed.  I am simply getting the wrong display information.  If I create a label and set its text to

```
label1.Text =((IWebSocketConnection)SocketList.Items[0]).ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress;
```

it displays the IP number

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be an alternative approach, but one thing you could do is flatten out the list members you need to display and bind to that.

For example:

```
var SocketInfos = sockets.Select((s) => new {ClientIpAddress = s.ConnectionInfo.ClientIpAddress,
                                             Socket = s}).ToList();

ListBox1.DataSource=SocketInfos ;
ListBox1.DisplayMember="ClientIpAddress";
```

You'd need to regenerate the list whenever you change the source list though.

This way you can still get back to the selected Socket Instance from the selected ListBox Item.

Comment: When I attempt this I get the error: "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource." at the ListBox1.DataSrouce line

Comment: Try just adding `.ToList()` on the end of the select. Have updated the answer.

Comment: That seemed to do it.  Thanks alot.  I would have thought this to be easier than that, but oh well

Comment: Don't think the databind is up for going deep into an object structure.